# How to fix java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found?

Tags: linux

I have an error, How to fix it in linux elemetary os?
I install JDK 11 on my os
when i type ./sdkmanager show this error
I install android studio but not running because require sdk

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
```

Comment: modules are supported in java 9 and above, looks like sdkmanager is not compatible with JDK 11. use java 8.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Mint 19 and openJDK11 installed.
After a lot of searches and failures, I finally made these things(thanks to the contributors):

## 1) Download

`openjdk10... wget` from [this link](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk10/10.0.2/19aef61b38124481863b1413dce1855f/13/openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz)

## 2) Alternate /bin/java and javac

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java \    .../jdk-10.0.2/bin/java 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac \    .../jdk-10.0.2/bin/javac 1

sudo update-alternatives --config java

sudo update-alternatives --config javac

java --version

javac --version

.../jdk-10.0.2/bin/java --version
```

## 3) REPLACE

`../jdk-10.0.2/lib/security/cacerts` FOR `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/security/cacerts`

## 4) Export

```
JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee
```

## 5) Now the following works

`.../tools/bin/sdkmanager`

Comment: This answer looks so convoluted (or maybe it's an English language fluency though). In simple terms, the answer is about degrading the JDK to be < 11. This can be easily achieved by simply running `sudo update-alternatives --config java` from the terminal. That way, the headache of trying to figure-out these commands above will be unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

please try to switch to JDK 8, this solved my issue.

Double check [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25811) as well.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The only option we have is to downgrade the java version.
My java version is `12`.

I wasted a few hours trying to resolve `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

After a ton of SO, github, googling I found this article regarding the deprecation of
[Java EE modules](https://jaxenter.com/jdk-11-java-ee-modules-140674.html)

I had to downgrade my java version to 1.8.